# Copying Column Values using as referencing a third column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['client_1', 'a', 5], ['client_1', 'b', 3],
                   ['client_2', 'a', 4], ['client_2', 'b', 8],
                   ['client_3', 'a', 1], ['client_3', 'b', 2]], columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'NumCol'])
╔══════════╦══════╦════════╗
║   Col1   ║ Col2 ║ NumCol ║
╠══════════╬══════╬════════╣
║ client_1 ║ a    ║      5 ║
║ client_1 ║ b    ║      3 ║
║ client_2 ║ a    ║      4 ║
║ client_2 ║ b    ║      8 ║
║ client_3 ║ a    ║      1 ║
║ client_3 ║ b    ║      2 ║
╚══════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

I want to create a column called 'Col3' which for every client should have Col2 value corresponding to NumCol values, e.g.

```
╔══════════╦══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║   Col1   ║ Col2 ║ NumCol ║ Col 3 ║
╠══════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ client_1 ║ a    ║      5 ║ a     ║
║ client_1 ║ b    ║      3 ║ a     ║
║ client_2 ║ a    ║      4 ║ b     ║
║ client_2 ║ b    ║      8 ║ b     ║
║ client_3 ║ a    ║      1 ║ b     ║
║ client_3 ║ b    ║      2 ║ b     ║
╚══════════╩══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Is there a pandas-pythonic way to acchieve this?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC `idxmax` with `transform`

```
df['New']=df.Col2.reindex(df.groupby('Col1').NumCol.transform('idxmax')).values
df
       Col1 Col2  NumCol New
0  client_1    a       5   a
1  client_1    b       3   a
2  client_2    a       4   b
3  client_2    b       8   b
4  client_3    a       1   b
5  client_3    b       2   b
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you